# WSO2 EMM Android Agent App Issue 'Connection Failed'

Tags: android, wso2, mdm, agent

I have installed the latest version of the WSO2 EMM v1.1.0. Followed all of the Installing, Deployment, and Running documentation.

The server is up and running, I added my Gmail info into the setting in the EMM console so I can send out invites. I added a user and sent an invite. It is received by the client phone (connected on the same LAN as the server). The app can be downloaded. I put in the server IP address, the users email and the password given in the email.

When I hit the 'Register' button I get this prompt, **"'Connection Failed' Server is unavailable. Please contact administrator."**

I have done two clean installs of the WSO2 EMM software, re-imputed the IP address in the Android client app, and have actually tried both "HTTP ; 9763" and "HTTPS ; 9443" within the CommonUtilities class.

I am at a loss as what to try next, any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you check whether 9763 (http) port is accessible from your connection?

Comment: Netstat on the Ubuntu 12.04 laptop where the server is located says both 9443 and 9763 are in **'LISTEN'** state. The app Port Detective on the Android (4.3) client which is connected to the same Wifi network says both ports are **'open'** but the description says **'not available'**.

Comment: From within two Android phones browser connected on the wifi, I tried various versions of http://192.168.1.100:9763/emm (EMM console) which redirects me to http://localhost:9763/emm and says web page not available. But it will allow me to access http://192.168.1.100:9763/carbon (Management console) which actually redirects me to https://192.168.1.100:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp.

Comment: Is that enough info to know if the ports are accessible, or is there something else I should try to test it?

Comment: If you can see the carbon console from the browser that's fine. This issue happens when device is not able to connect to the server. Please make sure you have added the correct IP address to the app. You can check and change the IP address at anytime from the app settings. And also try to login as default admin username: admin, password: admin

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that, logging in as Admin worked. I still need to figure out whats going wrong with the invites. I noticed in the EMM Console that under Configuration-Users it does not display the users, it just says "showing 1 of 1 entries" but the users are not actually displayed. Did you have this problem?

Comment: This error shows up in the Terminal log, when I try look for users in the EMM Console ** ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.user:js} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRoles" of null (/emm/modules/user.js#196) **

Answer (score 0):

Is your android phone and your server connected to the same network connection? If so, can you connect your android phone to your PC which has eclipse (with android sdk configured) and let me know what is displayed in the logcat when you hit the 'Register' button.

Comment: They are on the same network, the server is on an Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. here is the logcat after connecting the device and running the agent app and clicking the register button a couple of times. The app on the phone says, **'Authentication Failed' Incorrect login information. Please try again.** . The username and password used were the ones sent with the invite email to this device. Will post Logcat on next comment

Comment: D/dalvikvm(3882): Late-enabling CheckJNI
D/libEGL(3882): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL(3882): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL(3882): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/OpenGLRenderer(3882): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: V/RenderScript(3882): 0x5929ffd8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
D/dalvikvm(3882): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 2% free 9233K/9348K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(3882): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 2% free 9637K/9756K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm(3882): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 175K, 3% free 9976K/10188K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
D/ServerUtils(3882): Attempt #1 to register
E/(3882): out

Comment: V/ServerUtils(3882): 192.168.1.100Posting '{password=3qQUT5, username=bob.taylor.inl@gmail.com}' to http://192.168.1.100:9763/emm/api/devices/clientkey
V/ServerUtils(3882): Posting 'password=3qQUT5&username=bob.taylor.inl@gmail.com' to http://192.168.1.100:9763/emm/api/devices/clientkey
W/ActivityThread(3882): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

Comment: D/dalvikvm(3882): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 811K, 9% free 9676K/10524K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
V/Check Reg Success(3882): From Demo Server: successfully added device!
D/ServerUtils(3882): Attempt #1 to register
E/(3882): out

Comment: /ServerUtils(3882): 192.168.1.100Posting '{password=3qQUT5, username=bob.taylor.inl@gmail.com}' to http://192.168.1.100:9763/emm/api/devices/clientkey
V/ServerUtils(3882): Posting 'password=3qQUT5&username=bob.taylor.inl@gmail.com' to http://192.168.1.100:9763/emm/api/devices/clientkey
W/DefaultRequestDirector(3882): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
V/Check Reg Success(3882): From Demo Server: successfully added device!
D/ServerUtils(3882): Attempt #1 to register
E/(3882): out

Comment: Thats a mess, sorry man, if there is a better way to show you the logcat let me know.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to so late. From the logs it, it looks like for the username you are sending the email address. In version 1.1.0, the username is by default the "Username" that you entered in the add user page in the page.
Please enter the Username and try register using the app.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it working. Your right the guide says to user the Email address as the username, but it is just the user name. And on top of it a lot of my connection issue problems had to do with a faulty router that my company gave me. Thanks for the help. Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: The user guide[1] for registering an Android device mentions to "Enter your username provided in the email". Can you tell me where in the guide says to use the email address as the username? So that it can be corrected.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM110/Registering+an+Android-powered+Device

Comment: Userguide -> Registering a Device -> Registering an Android-Powered device: "Username - Enter your email address as the username." But this is for the 1.0.1 documentation. So it was my bad, but some of the links do take you to older version's of the guide. For example if you click on the root link back to Enterprise Mobility Manager 1.0.1/... the links like "Getting Started" takes you to the older documentation, which is misleading and did trip me up at first.

Comment: @HarboughForPresident: The documentation is now updated. Thank you for informing us.

Answer (score 0):

You have to login to EMM app atleast once before doing a device enrollment. This could be due to APIs being not published to the API store we have embedded in the EMM server. Check on the following path https://{server_domain}:9443/productapistore. Check whether there exist any published APIs. Also check your connection. Check whether you can access the EMM app through your mobile browser.